# programs running on startup without being in startup folder

Tags: windows, startup

some program (sort of malware) is running on my windows 7 at startup, but my startup folder is empty (even after removing the hidden and system attrib of all the programs in the folder). But msconfig shows the script that was running.

This means that programs can run on startup without actually being in the startup folder.

Please help me by explaining, how these softwares do this, or any concept of startup that i am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/109/):

> Add a new startup application 
>   Open your registry and find the key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run].
>
> For each program you want to start automatically create a new string value using a descriptive name, and set the value of the string to the program executable.
>
> For example, to automatically start Notepad, add a new entry of "Notepad"="c:\windows\notepad.exe".

Answer (score 4):

Goto MSCONFIG and Remove the check mark for that particular App. then you are good go

[image]

Comment: I know this thing. But i want to know why the .exe shown by msconfig not shown in startup folder. Therefore want to know another way of making a program run on startup.

Comment: Well, it depends on the App or virus which made the registry for startup. if you want to run any progam by startup you can do it by some registry modification or just placing it in start up folder. so these are the famous two ways for virus developers(for me)

Comment: @aaveg Check out that "Location" column.

Comment: @Kirk I wanted to know the registry method. I don't know much about it (i can google search it now). Are there any other "not so famous" ways for virus developers?

Comment: Yes many methods, Sysinternals Autoruns show almost all.

Comment: yes of coz! like a service pattern virus. that wont be in the msconfig or startup. almost stealthy